# "Is himself in?" What does it mean?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, dialects, reflexives, hiberno-english

Context - A stranger knocks on your door and asks "Is himself in?"

> [himself](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/himself), a [reflexive pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_pronoun), here seems to be used for a nominative pronoun.

Comment: This construction is never used in the US. In my experience with UK usage, it seems to be vaguely related to the concept of "*the man himself*", as in "t*he central character*" or "*the man of the house*". I've also seen it used ironically, e.g. applied to a particularly supercilious cat or other pet. But at this point I'll bow out and let our resident Brits weigh in. (PS: of course "*Is X in?*" means "*Is X here?*", so in sum I'm suggesting that "*Is himself in?*" is asking "*Is the man of the house home right now?*", though I'd expect the asker to be familiar with the "himself" person).

Comment: In the US you might, eg, ask a receptionist or secretary who you know well if "himself" is in, when you are aware that the receptionist/secretary views "himself" (presumably the big boss) as somewhat stuck up and full of himself.  This is definitely not formal US English, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common expression in Irish English. A [podcast from the Minnesota Public Radio site](http://minnesota.publicradio.org/radio/podcasts/grammar_grater/archive/2009/02/05/) describes its use and origin, citing Brian Ó Broin of the English department at William Paterson University in New Jersey:

> Ó Broin explains that in Irish English, the two normally reflexive pronouns **himself** and **herself** can be used nominatively—that is, they can be used to indicate the subject of a sentence or even with the verb to be. "So you can say things like 'It's herself' or 'Is himself in?'" Ó Broin says.
>
> Ó Broin clarifies that **himself** and **herself** can often be used to refer to somebody of importance, or at least somebody of importance to both the speaker and the listener in the conversation, and that there's a clear understanding between the speaker and listener who is being spoken about. "For example, my sister is in hospital right now about to give birth to a baby," Ó Broin says. "So if I were to call her husband up and say, 'How's **herself**?' it would be absolutely understood that I'm not speaking about Michelle Obama or my mother. The person in question is my sister."
>
> Ó Broin is quite certain this usage came out of Irish Gaelic. He says that Gaelic does not have a reflexive equivalent to English, but that when Irish people assemble a sentence that requires some sort of stress or an intensifier on the subject, they will use the Irish word, féin which means self. "So the Irish sentence, Sé féin atá ann, meaning 'It's him—that one,' becomes translated into Hiberno-English as 'It's **himself**,'" Ó Broin says. "So it's almost certain that Irish Gaelic is the origin of this phrase, 'It's **himself**.'"

In your example, the stranger is almost certainly asking to speak with the master of the house.

Comment: Hum, that last bit is not very accurately put by Mr. Ó Broin—if it's just “stress or an intensifier on the subject” you're after, Irish has the very useful emphatic pronouns which are a much better fit than _X féin_. If you're just stressing that it's _him_ (not someone else) who's there, you'd say “Eisean atá ann”. _É féin atá ann_ almost invariably means either ‘he's there himself’ or ‘the hubby is there’, as it were.

Comment: Also, though he doesn't say it in quite so many words, _himself_ and _herself_ used nominatively is nearly always used to refer to someone in their capacity of being a _spouse_. It would be much less common to hear it used about, say, a boss (unless you were talking to the boss’s spouse and were well acquainted with both).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I’m pretty sure I’ve heard this used in the "personal of importance" sense, like the Queen’s ministers exclaiming "Oh my! Has Herself seen this yet?"  It might be parody; dunno.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet My knowledge of IE is literary; but certainly Pegeen Mike is referred to as *herself* throughout *Playboy*, and she's clearly the boss, although she's the daughter, not the wife, of the widowed tavern-keeper.

Comment: @tchrist & Stoney: Note that I was talking about the Irish version there, not the Hibernian English one. Its usage is broader in English than in Irish, and a boss is (in my experience, at least) much more likely to be _him-/herself_ than _é/í féin_. Even so, there is more to it than just stressing or intensifying the person—there is a hint of insolent, twinkly-eyes humour about the phrase, particularly in English, when used to refer to someone in their capacity of other things than spouses. Or at least there is in my experience.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'll have to look up what's been done in the last 30 years in the way of postcolonialist readings of Synge. :)